# Resolve Generic Interface with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Wondering if it's possible to achieve the following:

```
container.GetInstance<IWordFacade<,,,>>();
```

So far I haven't been able to.  Here are some code samples:

```
IWordFacade<T1,T2,T3,T4>{
    T1 DoSomething(T2);
}

public class ConcreteFacade1 : IWordFacade<int,long,double,decimal>{
    int DoSomething(long param){
        //....
    }
}

public class ConcreteFacade2 : IWordFacade<short,string,float,char>{
    short DoSomething(string param){
        // ...
    }
}
```

... given these types/classes I am trying to find something that will allow me to return either ConcreteFacade1 or 2 based on how the container is configured to resolve the interface (which is where I'm having trouble).

I have tried:

```
container.Register(typeof(IWordFacade<,,,>), typeof(ConcreteFacade1));
```

resulting in an error stating: IWordFacade<,,,> is not a registered open generic type.

Comment: And what type would you expect the container to return for you? Can you give a bit more context?

Comment: I would want either of the ConcreteFacade types depending on how the container is configured... that's dependent upon a certain app.config configuration and is determined at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you supplied is not valid C# and will not compile. You can't specify an open-generic type within the < and > tags. You have to specify a closed generic type. The following however is valid C#:

```
container.GetInstance(typeof(IWordFacade<,,,>));
```

Although this would compile, this still will not work in Simple Injector (or any other DI framework), since frameworks always want to return you a concrete instance, but you can't create an instance for an open generic type, which is quite obvious, since an open-generic type is just a template. You need to fill in the blanks to be able to create an instance. In other words, you need a closed-generic type.

But how should the container know which closed-generic instance it should create given this open generic type? There is an endless number of possible permutations.

Although you can register an open-generic type like this:

```
container.Register(typeof(IWordFacade<,,,>), typeof(WordImpl<,,,>));
```

You will have to request for a closed-generic interface for your DI container to be able to resolve it:

```
container.GetInstance<IWordFacade<Foo, Bar, FooBar>>();
```

or

```
container.GetInstance(typeof(IWordFacade<Foo, Bar, FooBar>));
```

**UPDATE**

From your update I understand that there is that you either register `ConcreteFacade1` or `ConcreteFacade2`, based on the config file, but never both. To be able to do this (in C#) you need a non-generic interface, otherwise you will only be able to program against `System.Object`, which is not very useful (and type-safe). So let your generic `IWordFacade<T1,T2,T3,T4>` inherit from the following non-generic interface:

```
interface IWordFacade {
    object DoSomething(object value);
}
```

This way you can make the following registration:

```
contianer.Register<IWordFacade, ConcreteFacade1>();
```

And you can resolve:

```
container.GetInstance<IWordFacade>();
```

Or of course inject `IWordFacade` into the constructor of a different type.

You now need to implement two methods into the implementations. If you have several implementations, it gets useful to define a base class. This base class can implement the non-generic interface method:

```
public abstract class WordFacadeBase<T1, T2, T3, T4> : IWordFacade<T1, T2, T3, T4> {
    public abstract T1 DoSomething(T2 value);
    object IWordFacade.DoSomething(object value) {
        return DoSomething(T2)value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help steven - and sorry about that typo in the beginning for the registration (was typing quickly and from mem). In any case... I really want to avoid having to supply the generic types as I make a call to container.GetInstance() quite a bit.  So, what I have done is to use some .net methods to achieve what I was looking for

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks for the update - that's exactly what I was trying to do and what I ended up implementing as there was no other way to accomplish this. Unfortunately, I have to call the GetInstance() method in more than a few spots (word addin) and didn't want the maintenance to become a nightmare.  Thanks for the insight and for writing that up -saved me the time :)

Comment: Is this a correct way to use in ASP.NET application. GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(MyApp.ILogger)). Thanks.

Comment: @Dilhan that question is impossible to answer without the proper context. You might want to try posting a new question here on SO.